# Шифрование функций в проекте

Tags: шифрование, метапрограммирование, самомодификация

Собсно сабж, кто сталкивался, как реализовать?

Требуется приложение с зашифрованым кодом (часть приложения начнет работать после ввода ключа по которому функции расшифруются), по сути тут речь о морфировании кода на "лету" в ходе выполнения приложения. желательно теория (книги, статьи), и примеры (в идеале на паскалях).

Comment: Для x86 можете еще поискать информацию об исполнении кода в стеке (обычно используется для взлома).

Работает на реальном железе, если стек не защищен от исполнения.

Вообще, если есть привиллегии, то можно ооткрыть доступ к сегменту кода по записи. Тогда можете зашифровать часть кода на диске в загрузочном модуле, а расшифровать его уже загруженный в память.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самомодификация и шифрование кода идут друг с другом.

Посмотрите [пример самомодификации кода](http://www.insidepro.com/kk/277/277r.shtml).

Возможно пригодится [полиморфный генератор](http://www.insidepro.com/kk/084/084r.shtml).

Comment: Несовсем то, но почитать было оч интересно

Answer (score 2):

Такие фишки можно делать только когда есть виртуальная машина, на уровне которой инструкции зашифрованы или как-то модифицированы и потом в ходе выполнения дешифруются в инструкции процессора. Или как вариант когда есть специализированный процессор, который шифрует/дешифрует инструкции на лету. Такие спец.процессоры любят ребята из гебешных структур - вам туда :)

Если рассматривать ситуацию попроще, то такой морфинг на лету можно делать на Java с кастомным загрузчиком классов - [статья здесь](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2003-05/01-qa-0509-jcrypt.html)

**P.S.** Это конечно же не совсем морфинг, поскольку под "настоящим" морфингом я бы понимал хаотичную самомодификацию кода на лету. Это так сказать статический морфинг кода.

Comment: Дык. можно ведь и без виртуальной машины...

Comment: интересуют именно варианты без виртуальных машин, так то уже реализовано, есть вирт машина паскалей для которой "скрипты" шифрованы до воода ключа.